# correct method to Use sub string in where clause mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, substring

I have a table in `mysql` with column called `type`. contents are below

```
Type
Test 12
Test abc
start 1
start abcd
end 123
```

Now I want to select records where `type` starts with `Test`

Expected result:

```
Test 12
Test abc
```

But I am getting either

Test 12
   or empty results

I have tried like below:

```
select * from table where type = 'Test 12'
select * from table where type = '%Test%'
select * from table where type = '%Test'
```

What should be the correct `sql` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Like keyword

```
select * from table where type LIKE 'Test%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do partial matches you need the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type LIKE 'Test%'
```

Comment: %Test **ends** with Test and not starts with it.

Comment: @JacquesAmar Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The equality (`=`) operator doesn't accept wild cards. You should use the `like` operator instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type LIKE 'Test%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sooo close! You want to **start** with the string, then don't use % in the start, and use `LIKE` instead of `=`

```
select * from table where type LIKE 'Test%'
```